# How to make Functionappname, region and appserviceplan value dynamic in Azure Java Funciton App?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-functions, pom.xml, azure-java-sdk

Based on most of the tutorials, it is suggested to add the FunctionAppName, Region, AppServicePlan in the pom.xml file. I will have to deploy this function app to various environments set up(different resource groups). I'd want to give the flexibility to the dev-ops team to add/edit this information before deploying the function app to the respective environment.  Is there a way I can pass this value separately without hardcoding them in my pom.xml?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java-function?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

If we need to add the parameters dynamically in pom.xml file. We need to add a dynamic property in a Pom.xml file.

```
<project>
. . .
    <build>
    . . .
         <plugins>
            . . .
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                                <!-- function app name -->
                                <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                                <!-- function app resource group -->
                                <resourceGroup>>${Resourcegroup}</resourceGroup>
                                <!-- function app service plan name -->
                                <appServicePlanName>>${AppServiceName}</appServicePlanName>
                                . . .
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit your `_pom.xml_` file update the settings:

Open your `_pom.xml_` in the **Cloud Shell** code editor.

```
code pom.xml
```

Locate the following artifact ID:

```
<artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

In the following `<configuration>` section, locate the `<resourceGroup>` element, and update it with the name of your ***resource group***. For example:

```
<resourceGroup>[resource group name]</resourceGroup>
```

Locate the `<region>` element, and update it with the name of the ***region*** where your *resource group* is located. For example:

```
<region>westus</region>
```

similar way you can add the values dynamically
Press `Ctrl+S` to save your `_pom.xml_` file, and then press `Ctrl+Q` to close the code editor.

Refer here for [azure-functions-app-with-maven-plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-azure-functions-app-with-maven-plugin/)